# Geoserver SLD style order not applied

Tags: geoserver, sld

I use a .sld to style a road layer according to 4 classes. Normally, the Painter algorithm should be applied: which come first is drawn first. But this does not really apply. The .sld are saved from QGIS.

This is the style with the black line on bottom:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>Roads</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>Roads</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>M</se:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>featurecod</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>1571</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#bee8ff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">20</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>A</se:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>featurecod</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>1572</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#d79e9e</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">10</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>B</se:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>featurecod</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>1574</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffebaf</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">5</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>streets</se:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:Or>
                <ogc:Or>
                  <ogc:Or>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                      <ogc:PropertyName>featurecod</ogc:PropertyName>
                      <ogc:Literal>1575</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                      <ogc:PropertyName>featurecod</ogc:PropertyName>
                      <ogc:Literal>1576</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  </ogc:Or>
                  <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>featurecod</ogc:PropertyName>
                    <ogc:Literal>1577</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Or>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>featurecod</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>1578</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              </ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>featurecod</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>1579</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

and i get this

[image]

while with the style with the black line on top

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>Roads</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>Roads</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>streets</se:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:Or>
                <ogc:Or>
                  <ogc:Or>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                      <ogc:PropertyName>featurecod</ogc:PropertyName>
                      <ogc:Literal>1575</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                      <ogc:PropertyName>featurecod</ogc:PropertyName>
                      <ogc:Literal>1576</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  </ogc:Or>
                  <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>featurecod</ogc:PropertyName>
                    <ogc:Literal>1577</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Or>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>featurecod</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>1578</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              </ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>featurecod</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>1579</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>M</se:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>featurecod</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>1571</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#bee8ff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">20</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>A</se:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>featurecod</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>1572</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#d79e9e</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">10</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>B</se:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>featurecod</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>1574</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffebaf</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">5</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

i get this:

[image]

which is the same.

Thanks!

Comment: could you add a note as to which rule is for which road type to save me having to parse the whole SLD to work out what is going on

Comment: streets are colored in black, and have the featurecod - 1575, 1576, 1577, 1578, 1579

Comment: M is blue and has featurecod = 1571

Comment: A is red and has featurecod = 1572

Comment: B is orange and has featurecod = 1574

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i remember my struggles with SLD (and IRC chats with Andrea) correctly the order of induvidual rules within a FeatureTypeStyle isn't significant (due to memory issues).

To ensure correct ordering you have to use more than one FeatureTypeStyle, see [this geoserver mailing list thread](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/SLD-drawing-order-td4948595.html)

Comment: Thank you! Now all seems logic. On a small example it worked my way. But on a lot of features no. Thanks again!